# Graphics freeze upon sleep

Tags: suspend, freeze

I have just installed Ubuntu 2022 and, yes, I did install the Nvidia drivers for my GTX 1060 graphics card. I have an Intel CPU.

When the system goes into sleep mode, some, but not all of the graphics freeze. I have two displays. On one display I had firefox open. Firefox froze but I was able to locate the reboot menu and restart that way. On reboot, graphics are OK but will encounter some kind of freeze while in sleep mode.

I tried entering the "display" mode and attempted to move the monitor display in that mode but that did not work.

Ubuntu is the only thing on that SSD.

Comment: Nmath, thank you for your reply and I apologize for the inexactness of my question.

Comment: I am running Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS  . 

I performed the following in order to install the drivers for my gtx1060. 

ubuntu-drivers devices
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
sudo reboot

Hopefully, this won't be like the old day (90's thru 2000's) where I needed to delete the nouveau drivers and recompile the kernel and pray that it all went well. I am prepared to do that again, if necessary but lets hope that it is not.

I also apologize because the formatting of my answer seems to be disappearing.

Comment: Nmath, thank you for your response. In 40 years of building computers this build represented my first use of M.2 drives. Impressive as they may be in terms of reliability and speed I have several of them (3) and they are really, really tough to get to inside the case. When loading OS's it is necessary to remove all other drives because there is still no way to absolutely insure that the OS that you are loading will go into the intended drive. You are probably correct about starting over but I would hate to have to do that again. any other ideas?